# Failed asserting that a traversable contains

Tags: php, phpunit

Test:

```
        $this->assertThat(
            array("James Bond", 'james@bond.com', '12345'),
            $this->contains('James Bond')
        );
```

works correctly, but if I change array to object:

```
        $this->assertThat(
            new User("James Bond", 'james@bond.com', '12345'),
            $this->contains('James Bond')
        );
```

then I have error:

> Failed asserting that a traversable contains 'James Bond'.

How to use assertThat with object and contains method?

My User class:

```
class User
{
    private $name;
    private $mail;
    private $pass;

    public function __construct($name, $mail, $pass)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->mail = $mail;
        $this->pass = $pass;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getMail()
    {
        return $this->mail;
    }

    public function getPass()
    {
        return $this->pass;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just do: `$this->assertContains('James Bond', $obj);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't give details about your User object, but apparently it's an intance of traversable.

Did you try [iterator_to_array](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.iterator-to-array.php) function ?

```
$this->assertThat(
        iterator_to_array(new User("James Bond", 'james@bond.com', '12345')),
        $this->contains('James Bond')
    );
```

Edit:

Actually  `contains` will check for an array values, here your properties are private (and that's great), so the only way to check a property values is by using its getter

Here is what you want to do

```
$this->assertEquals('James Bond', $user->getName());
```

Comment: User it is simple PHP class with fields name, email and  pass and getters. 
Your example throw: TypeError: Argument 1 passed to iterator_to_array() must implement interface Traversable, instance of User given

Comment: Give details (structure) about your user object by editing your question  to make things clear, we cannot really help you if we dont know what you are testing

Comment: Edited my answer!